# How can i paste the data stored from clip and use it for a different command

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, batch, ipconfig

I need to paste the result of clip command into netsh interface ip address

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4"') do SET result=%%i
echo %result:IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : =% | clip
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static %clip% 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate your questions on both SU and SO, so delete one of the copies.

Comment: @karan will do though i thought they were two different networks

Answer (score 0):

```
route change -p 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: what is the address you need to place after -p ?

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('ipconfig ^| find "IPv4"') do SET result=%%i
SET result=%result:IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : =%
echo %result% | clip
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static %result% 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1

endlocal
```